# MSQL Conditional Aggregate functions

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have the following table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE `divisions` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`));

  CREATE TABLE `div_postcodes` (
  `div_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `postcode` INT NOT NULL,
  `percentage` DECIMAL NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`div_id`, `postcode`));
```

the table stores information on postcodes, and which electorate they belong to, and what percentage of that postcode area belongs to that electorate.

What i am needing to get is the list of postcodes in each electorate, but i only want it to be in the list if it has the highest percentage, and hense the postcode should only appear once. If a group_concat could be used to join the postcodes into a string, that would be great as well.

For example: 
postcode is listed as followed:

```
div_id, postcode, percentage
601,    828,      90.10
602,    828,      9.90
```

I only want postcode 828 to be listed under div_id 601, since it covers 90%

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90997

Comment: Can you add sample data please? You could create a SQL Fiddle if you like: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: SQL Fiddle added to Post - i added data for 601 and 602, which have a common postcode of 828

Answer (score 0):

The following query will give you single combination of division and postcode - the one with highest percentage. Is that what you were looking for?

```
select div_id, postcode, max(percentage)
from div_postcodes
group by div_id, postcode
```

Comment: King of, i was hoping that i could get the postcodes in a group_concat, but your solution jogged my thoughts into the solution i was after

Comment: No worries about the upvote. Thank you. Glad you were able to figure out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select 
    d.div_id, group_concat(d.postcode)
from
    (select 
        div_id, postcode, max(percentage)
    from
        div_postcodes
    group by postcode) d
group by div_id
```